# Is there any way to join automatically lists with same values from the same set?

Tags: python

I have an array of lists and I will like to join all the lists with repeated values.

For example if I have the next array a:

```py
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[10,8,9],[72,3,6]])
```

The expected result should be:

```py
result=array([[ 1,  2,  3, 4, 6, 72],
              [ 10,  8,  9]])
```

Comment: and what if the 3rd item contains `6`: `[[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[10,8,6],[72,3,6]]` ? how the result should be distributed?

Comment: IN that case the result should be: `array([[ 1,  2,  3, 4, 6, 72, 10, 8, 6]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are talking about is a data structure known as "**Disjoint Set**".
While this is not in-built in python, a simple mock-up of this can be easily made for your case.

```py
def merge_sets (arrays): # arrays could be your np array
  sets = list()
  for a in arrays:
    sets.append(a)
  a, b = 0, 1
  while a < len(sets):
    if b < len(sets) and sets[a].intersect(sets[b]):
      c = sets[a].union(sets[b])
      sets.remove(a)
      sets.remove(b)
      sets.append(c)
  return sets
```

*P.S. This is just a rough implementation to demonstrate how you can do it. It has not been checked for fallacies.*